# How do you parse the sentence "He had Elizabeth read the letter aloud."?

Tags: phrases, verbs, linguistics

The [Stanford parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp) gave the following output. I think the word "read" should be tagged with VBN (past participle).

```
(ROOT
  (S
    (NP (PRP He))
    (VP (VBD had)
      (S
        (NP (NNP Elizabeth))
        (VP (VB read)
          (NP (DT the) (NN letter))
          (ADVP (RB aloud)))))
    (. .)))
```

Comment: The sentence in the body of your question is different to that of the question. Please include the complete sentence (unparsed) in the body, and change the title accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, it's edited

Comment: Have you tried using a substitute verb that has distinct forms in the present and past tense? That may throw some light.

Comment: I think it's correct- It's not a past participle. (It's pronounced 'reed', not 'red' here.)

Comment: Just got it. It means "He made the decision that Elizabeth would read the letter aloud". Am I correct?

Comment: Close. We have know way of knowing whether he 'asked' her or 'ordered' her or 'persuaded' her, but he somehow 'caused her to read the letter aloud.' *Have* here is a lexical verb, not an auxiliary.

Comment: I would probably parse it (the verb "read") in "He had her **read** the letter aloud" similar to "He had Elizabeth **be** quiet", "He had her **eat** the letter".

Answer (score 1):

As Jim notes in the comments, the parser is correct.

> It's not a past participle. (It's pronounced 'reed', not 'red' here.)